# Graph API Calendar getSchedule for mulitple users

Tags: microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar, microsoft-graph-api

Using the MS Graph SDK, I want to retrieve scheduled calendar items for multiple users (acknowledging the max number of users with a single query is 20).  However, I'm having difficulty understanding the structure of the RequestBuilder for this.  Here's my code:

```
List<string> users = new List<String>()
                {
                "userA@tst.xyz",
                "userB@tst.xyz"
                };

ICalendarGetScheduleCollectionPage result = await graphClient
            .Users["userA@tst.xyz"]
            .Calendar
            .GetSchedule(users, endTime, startTime, 15)
            .Request()
            .Header("Prefer", "outlook.timezone=\"Pacific/Auckland\"")
            .PostAsync();
```

I seem to have to have a default user and include that in `.Users["userA@tst.xyz"]` and then include them and all of the other users I want in my `List<string> users`.  Is that correct?  That doesn't seem that logical to me which makes me suspect my understanding is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameter in `.User["user_principal"]` means you will execute the query in the name of that user, but it always makes no sense as you're using client credential. It only represents the oppisite of `Me` here I think. There's a format in microsoft graph api, we usually query for someone's information by using `.User["user_principal"]`, just useless in this scenario.

And for `GetSchedule`, the user ids used here means this query will search for the availability information for these users.

===================================================

Pls refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-getschedule?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request) about the "getSchedule" feature.

> POST /me/calendar/getSchedule
>
> POST /users/{id|userPrincipalName}/calendar/getSchedule

You can see that this graph api provides 2 options, one for `client.Me.Calendar`, and another is for `client.User[userPrincipalName].Calendar`.

This means you can get the "GetSchedule" response with your own account(you get the credential in auth code/ROPC flow which needs you provide user information so that the credential can know who you are and can use "Me" in the request) or from a specific account(use e.g. clientcredential flow so that you have the permission to access all user via using User[userPrincipalName]).

Comment: Thanks.  I'm aware of that documentation and its examples.

I should add, I'm developing an application that uses the client credentials grant flow and so can't access user calendar using "Me".  That's why I've added the ".Users["userA@tst.xyz"]" request to the Request Builder.  However, I'm confused about the relationship of that and the schedules parameter in the .GetSchedule method.

Comment: `.Users["userA@tst.xyz"]` means you executing the query in the name of UserA, and parameters(user names) for `GetSchedule` means, this query is aim for getting the availability information for the users. I test this api and put any `member type` user id from your tenant in `Users[]` is ok. But not a guest user id.

Comment: Yes - that's the conclusion I've come to as well.
The nature of my application is the users included in the GetSchedule method's schedules parameter can only be from the tenant, so I'm just taking the first user in the schedules List and adding them to the .User component of the request builder.  Thanks for your help

Comment: @Peter Thanks for your reply and could you pls accept my post as the answer if you feel it helpful and that may help others who meet similar scenario to find it?